# new firebase: Error: Must pass a valid Firebase reference to $firebaseArray (not a string or URL)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase

For some reason, with this new firebase, `$firebaseArray` does not seem to work. I've tried `$firebaseArray(firebase.database().ref('users'))` but I'm getting this message:

> Error: Must pass a valid Firebase reference to $firebaseArray (not a string or URL)

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the firebase client library version 3 with the current version of angularfire, which doesn't yet support version 3. There's a pull request for an upgraded angularfire version that is in review and the author claims to be ready to release it imminently .  See https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/pull/717

In the meantime, you can either not use angularfire (see workaround below) or you can revert to the old firebase client library.

[EDIT] - Apparently this snippet isn't really an acceptable workaround because it doesn't return an array, but rather an object.  Please disregard...

```js
   
var self = this;
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref("users");
             usersRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
                 self.users = snapshot.val();
             });
```

Comment: It is a solution that is documented, but the need to return an ArrayList of what euesta on the route, so firebaseArray used, and how you indicate only returns an object.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I reverted to the old firebase for now.

Comment: Thanks! I figured, that's why I reverted back to the old firebase. I hope they get a fix pretty soon.